# CDT doesn't recognize GTK+ but compiles without errors

Tags: c++, eclipse, gtk, eclipse-cdt

I've installed `CDT` on `Eclipse Indigo` and installed `gtk+` libraries on to my linux system. And then I've tried compiling an example from the site, It compiled and ran well but in the editor, it says many errors but the compiler shows no errors.

[image: My Eclipse]

How can I fix it?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved this issue by setting the include paths

```
[Alt+Enter] --> Paths and Symbols
```

Add these for all the languages which exists.

```
/usr/include/atk-1.0
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gtk-2.0/include
/usr/include/gtk-2.0
/usr/include/cairo
/usr/include/glib-2.0
```

[image: A GTK Window]